# How create vf page that display listview of records selected from multiple objects(standard and custom) on custom button click

Tags: apex, visualforce

Hi I am new in salesforce development, and i wants to make a vf  page that display the list of records fetched from different object (standard and also some custom object). But i didn't find how to start building vf page with controller which retrive recodrds from different object display it on single vf page.

I hv very little knowledge how to built vf page with controller i.e MVP.

Pls suggest any Blog post and steps how to build such a page in salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

Is this what you are looking for?

https://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_compref_relatedList.htm

Without any Apex knowledge you can have a VF page that displays all child records related to a parent record.

I recommend you read this post 
https://developer.salesforce.com/page/Building_Visualforce_Pages_Using_the_Standard_Controller